# Do I need a database for generating WFS-T with QGIS-Server?

Tags: qgis, database, qgis-server

I have hard difficulties in understanding: I have a QGIS-Project (in QGIS) and I want to create a WFS-T by using QGIS-Server (and the QGIS-Server I have is connected with e.g. Windows-Server).

- Is the Data for the WFS-T stored in the QGIS-Server?
- Or do I need for WFS-T a DB, where QGIS-Server grabs the data?

The [QGIS-Documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/de/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/ogc_server_support.html) said nothing about a DB, instead it says "QGIS as Dataserver". But [this Blog](https://www.sigterritoires.fr/index.php/en/how-to-install-qgis-server-in-windows-10/) and others always talk about QGIS-Server in connection with a DB.

Comment: You can use any data source Shapefile, geopackage, DB to serve your data. Just make sure you enable all the wfs options in the QGIS server settings to be able to transact over QGIS server. If you need your wfst to be authenticated you would need to use the Authentification manager when setting up your project

Comment: Is not clear to me sorry. Let's say I have a Shapefile in my QGIS-Project. With QGIS-Server-Plugin I generate a WFS-T. A client somewhere else in the world connect to this WFS-T with his/her own Desktop-QGIS and changes e.g. geometries and attributes. When this client "saves" the changes - where this changes will be stored?

Comment: If you have activated WFS-T then the changes will be propagated to your shapefile. It is generally encouraged to use a database for such things but you can setup a demo and test and see what happens with the changes to your shapefile

Comment: I understand! The QGIS-Server grabs it from everywhere (like e.g. shapefile) and together with the Webserver it shoots the data out and back in. So it has not to be a database but it is recommended. Okay thanks I understand the process yet.